# How to select a specific area (in a polygon form) determined by some value range in a raster band?

Tags: raster, polygon, pyqgis, area, band

For example, I want create a vector layer with polygons that represents all areas where the elevation is between 500 and 600. Someone has any idea to help me? I'm using PyQgis 2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually done in a two-step process:

1. Reclassify your data so that values between 500-600 = 1 and all
   other values = 0
2. Convert the [raster data to vector data](http://manual.linfiniti.com/en/complete_analysis/raster_to_vector.html) based on the pixel value.

Comment: Variant of the same idea: If you need to do this work only once and you can accept to do some manual work you can use gdal_contour http://www.gdal.org/gdal_contour.html and create contour lines every 100 m. Open the vector file that gets created, delete everything except the 500 and 600 m contour lines  and finally build area from what is between these two lines.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, your ideia helped a lot, really ! And user30184, thanks too